# how to connect two models in html template?

Tags: python, django

I would like to create a simple forum with Python Django. The main thing I can not figure out is getting informations from two models.

I want to display: Post title, content, author, published date and signature. This is my post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'Homepage/base.html' %}


{% block content %}
      <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
      <h6>Kategoria: {{ post.category }} | Autor: {{ post.author }} | {{ post.published_date }}</h6>
      <p>{{ post.description|linebreaksbr }}</p>
      <p><hr>{{ HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SHOW SIGNATURE }}</p>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Homepage app models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

accounts app models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    website = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    signature = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)

    def create_profile(sender, **kwargs): 
        user = kwargs["instance"]
        if kwargs["created"]:
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
            user_profile.save()
    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.user.username
```

My full code is on https://github.com/Incybro/Forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just follow the relationships:

```
<p>{{ post.author.user.signature }}</p>
```

(Note, you've set the related_name from User to UserProfile to `user`, which makes no sense. You should leave it as the default, which would be `userprofile`.)

Comment: I deleted related_name from UserProfile.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your {{post.author}} won't be returning anything, change in to `{{post.author.get_full_name}}`

For signature, in your model you don't need to add any related name,

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in template,

```
{{post.author.userprofile.signature}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just return the relevant `UserProfile` model when you send the request?

```
def my_view(request):
    context = {}
    my_post = Post.objects.all.get(0) # get the post here
    my_user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=my_post.author)
    context['post'] = my_post
    context['user'] = my_user
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

Then, in your html, you can use those template tags.

```
{% block content %}
      <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
      <h6>Kategoria: {{ post.category }} | Autor: {{ post.author }} | {{ post.published_date }}</h6>
      {% autoescape on %}
      <p>{{ post.description|linebreaksbr }}</p>
      <p><hr>{{ user.signature }}</p>
      {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
```

You want the `autoescape` so people can't change the look or function of your site by injecting malicious HTML/JS into your site.